# How does one consolidate multi-dimensional arrays?

Tags: javascript, multidimensional-array

I am trying to get one array with a complete string:

['...']

Given:

Array1 = ['...', ['...'], ['...', 2, 'x']]

This should handle any size array*

Define a function, `zooInventory`, that accepts a multi-dimensional array of
animal facts.

`zooInventory` should return a new, flat array. Each element in the new array
should be a sentence about each of the animals in the zoo.

What I have currently:

```
const zooInventory = array => {
    let finalArray = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
      let currentElement = array[i];
     if (!(Array.isArray(currentElement))) {
         finalArray.push(currentElement);
     } else {
         zooInventory(currentElement);
// I thought I could push the currentElement back to beginning to handle additional arrays 
     }
    }
  return finalArray;
}
```

Where my heads at:

I thought I could get away with having it push(...array) in the else statement.

My batman belt contains beginner methods... slice, splice, spread.

What method would be best practice?

Comment: this->"_return a new, flat array._" makes my Robin brain think about, well, `flat()` [reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flat)

Answer (score 0):

Simply use the `.flat()` method as shown in the snippet below.

More information here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flat

```js
let arrayOne = ['...', ['...'], ['...', 2, 'x']];

console.log(arrayOne.flat());
```